# Which image type to use in opengl

Tags: image, opengl-es-2.0

When programing for Android using OpenGL I seem to be able use BMP, JPG and PNG file types for my images.
Which (if any) is best?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an OpenGL concern as once you have the `Graphics.Bitmap` object the source is largely irrelevant.

So this degenerates into essentially 'Which file format is better?' which can be answered in other questions such as [What is the difference between “JPG” / “JPEG” / “PNG” / “BMP” / “GIF” / “TIFF” Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419584/what-is-the-difference-between-jpg-jpeg-png-bmp-gif-tiff-i)

Ultimately I would suggest using a `PNG`. Why?

`BMP` images are (generally) uncompressed - they are exact representations of the image but can be very large in size.

`PNG` is a lossless compression format - when it is uncompressed, it is an exact representation of the image.

`JPG` is a lossy compression format - when it is uncompressed, it is *not* an exact representation and thus there may be visual artifacts.

So, both `BMP` and `PNG` result in an exact representation of the original image, while `PNG` files will be smaller in size which is important for mobile applications.

Comment: Good point on the Bitmap object as far as OpenGL is concerned. No one else has pointed that out for the many questions similar to this. I suppose it should be which format is better for the BitmapFactory.